# Hint Change Error From Java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:hint="Name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And I want to change the Hint Text form Java when a switch button is touched, but this is what happens using this code:

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isTouched) {
                isTouched = false;
                if (isChecked) {
                    _nameText.setHint("Shop Name");
                    _inputPiva.setHint("ho la cacca");
                }
                else {
                    _nameText.setHint("Name");
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

How can I set the hint like the light-blue one?

Comment: You need to set the hint on the `TextInputLayout`, instead of the `EditText`.

Comment: change textColorHint to blue in xml

Comment: @MikeM. How can I declare it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @MikeM. I mean that there isn't any id on the TextInputLayout, so, how can I let java know what and where it is?

Comment: Just add an `id` to the `<TextInputLayout>` element, and find it the same way you did the `EditText`, with `findViewById()`.

Comment: Oh yes... what a stupid question, sorry, I need a break....

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! @MikeM.

Answer (score 1):

Step1: "Programatic":**editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));**

Step2: "Xml":**android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"**

You can get the hint of edittext like this

```
    editText.setHint("My conditional hint");
    final String str = hi.getHint().toString();
```

Then after toggle Onclick listener place the code

```
editText.setText(str); //It will replace the text
```

Comment: Yes, but I mean, the "Shop Name" in the second image, should be in place of the "Name"

Comment: Can you try my updated code...Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you, but I solved! It was because I was using a TextInputLatout, so I had to set the hint I wanted to it and not to the EditText